# PHP convert specific character

Tags: php, character, decode, encode

I have string like this - "Divizia NaÅ¢ionalÄ", and want to convert it to "Divizia Naţională", which is correct string. What heppand, how to remove this special characters? Hich PHP function I can use? Now to convert it to " Devizia Nationala" which is best readable for everyone?

Comment: Look up Character encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

1. Use UTF8
2. Be sure your data source is UTF8
3. Learn how to force browsers to display UTF8
4. Don't use other encodings, convert everything to UTF8 as soon as possible
5. Your best support on this mission is [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)